# how can i connect client to server database which is mysql using LAN

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Database=825records;server=localhost;user id=root;password="
        con.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
```

how can i connect client to server database which is mysql using LAN

Comment: Instead of 'localhost' you can write server IP adress or you can even try with servers computer name since they are in LAN.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Database=825records;server=serveripaddress;user id=root;password="
        con.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
```